# AngularJS how to wait till a promise is returned

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS app has functions like this.

```js
function createDefaultRequest() {
  
  var paramServiceId = currentUser.serviceId;
  var paramStatuses = myRequestService.getStatuses();      

  var paramSubServices = [];      
  paramSubServices = getSubService(paramServiceId);
  vm.subServices = paramSubServices;

  var defaultRequest = myRequestService.createRequest(
    paramServiceId, paramSubServices, paramStatuses);

  return defaultRequest;
}

function getSubService(paramServiceId) {
  medicalServiceFactory.subservices().query({
      serviceId: paramServiceId
    },
    function(subServicesData) {

      subServicesData.forEach(function(thisSubservice) {
        thisSubservice.ticked = true;
      });
      return subServicesData;
    },
    function(response) {
      vm.errorMessage = response.statusText;
    });
}
```

I would like `myRequestService.createRequest(...)` to wait until the `getSubService()` returns. Right now the `paramSubServices` and `vm.subServices` are always empty `[]`. How do I achieve this without moving the `createRequest(...)` in the callback block of the `.query()`?  Thanks.

Comment: Does an answer solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `$q` dependency, where you can customize the async request.
You should take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or the snippet below.

```js
console.clear();
var _app = angular.module("ServiceModule", []);

_app.service("RequestSubService", ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
 this.getSubService = function(pServiceId) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
    
    //Timeout just to simulate the time it could take (e.g. 5sec)
    $timeout(function() {
     if(pServiceId > 0)
       deferred.resolve({status: 'success', serviceId: pServiceId})
      else
       deferred.reject({status: 'error', serviceId: pServiceId});
    }, 5000);
    
    return deferred.promise;
  };
}]);

_app.service("RequestService", ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {
 this.createRequest = function(pServiceId) {
    return "Created request with serviceId: " + pServiceId;
  }
}])

_app.controller("ServiceCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', 'RequestSubService', 'RequestService', function($scope, $timeout, requestSubService, requestService) {
  $scope.serviceId = 1;
  
  $scope.fetchServices = function() {
   $scope.message = "Fetching ...";
   var promise = requestSubService.getSubService($scope.serviceId);
    promise.then(
      //Success
      function(data) {
        if(data.status === 'success')
          $scope.message = requestService.createRequest(data.serviceId);
      },

      //Error
      function(error) {
        $scope.message = "An error occured. ServiceId: " + error.serviceId;
      }
    );
  }
  $scope.fetchServices();
}]);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ServiceModule">
  <div ng-controller="ServiceCtrl">
    <span>Input value > 0 will result in success. If value equals 0 it'll throw an error.</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="serviceId" ng-change="fetchServices()"/>
    <span>{{message}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your service returns a promise, you can wait for the promise just the key word `.then()`:

```
myService.myFunction().then(function(result) {
    // Success callback      
}).then(function(reason) {
    // Error callback
});
```

---

From the [`$q` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> **`then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback])`**
>
> Regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls
>   one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the
>   result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument:
>   the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may
>   be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before
>   the promise is resolved or rejected.